# How can I create a zoom animation from one ng-view to another?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, angularjs

My screen will be broke into 4 equal rectangles each with a chart in. I want the user to be able to click on a chart and the application then to zoom into a new view which is that chart as a whole page.

SO I would like the set-up:

app/charts displays all charts. Then when user selects a chart (say chart-1), the app navigates to app/charts/chart-1.

I would like the chart that is clicked to expand into view until it takes up the whole screen (the new view).

I'm open to any approach to this. CSS, javascript libraries, hacks (maybe just use one view and zoom in on the selected div?) I want be able to navigate to a full screen chart by url though...

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper  {selected_class}">
  <div ng-click="selected_class='top-left'" class="top-left"></div>
  <div ng-click="selected_class='top-right'" class="top-right"></div>
  <div ng-click="selected_class='bottom-left'" class="bottom-left"></div>
  <div ng-click="selected_class='bottom-right'" class="bottom-right"></div>
</div>


.top-left .top-left{ transform:scale(2); } etc
```